# How can I take a big amount of GET parameters and filter a query depending on them cleanly?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel, lumen

I have this controller for a RESTful API I am building in Laravel Lumen which takes a relatively big amount of parameters and parses them into where queries, and data is fetched depending on if they were provided. For example,

```
GET /nodes?region=California
GET /nodes?ip=127.0.0.1
```

I am currently taking them in the constructor, building an array of the parameters (since I couldn't figure out how to get the raw get array in Lumen and it would be inconvenient because I already have other parameters there), and filtering out the null values (I am setting values to null if they are not in the query).

Now, when it comes to filtering the values each in the array, I am doing it by a foreach array. This is the cleanest way I could figure out to do it, without too much code (I don't want to make my controllers too fat.).
Is there any other way to do this cleanly, maybe with separation of functions/classes?

Here is my constructor code:

```
/**
 * Get some values before using functions.
 * 
 * @param Request $request Instance of request.
 */
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->offset = (int) $request->input('offset', 0);

    // TODO: I'm not sure how to implement this, code in question
    $this->filters = [
        'region' => $request->input('region', null),
        'name' => $request->input('name', null),
        'ip' => $request->input('ip', null)
    ];

    $this->filters = array_filter($this->filters, function ($v) {
        return !is_null($v);
    });

    // Set a sane SQL limit.
    $this->limit = 5;
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

And the controller code:

```
/**
 * List all nodes.
 * 
 * @return [string] [JSON containing list of nodes, if sorted.]
 */
public function all()
{
    try {
        // use filters provided
        $data =  Nodes::limit($this->limit)->offset($this->offset);

        foreach ($this->filters as $filter => $value) {
            $data->where($filter, $value);
        }

        $data = $data->get();
        $response = $this->respond($data);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response = $this->respondServerError('Could not retrieve data from database.');
    }

    return $response;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So any time I have to do filtering of a resource-list in an API, here's how I do it.

First off though, before I begin, a quick tip concerning getting the Request object when you're in your controller method: If you add `Request $request` as a parameter for your `all()` function, you will have access to the $request variable there, same as your constructor. So the complete signature would be `public function all(Request $request)`. Controller methods have the same magic dependency injection that other class constructors get in Laravel/Lumen. Alternatively, in your function you can always ask the `app()` function to give you an object of a specific class. Because the Request object is bound in the Container to just 'request', you can ask for the full class name, or just 'request': `$request = app('request');`

So once I have my request object, inside my controller method I like to go through each filter either as a group, or one-by-one, depending on how complex each filter is. Sometimes filters are complex, like a list of comma-separated IDs that need to be exploded into an array. If it's just simple string filters though, I tend to throw the list into an array and run through that.

Here's an example function to illustrate some ideas:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
    //Create a User object to append WHERE clauses onto
    $user = app('App\Models\User');

    //Run through our simple text fields
    foreach(['first_name', 'last_name', 'region', 'ip'] as $field) {
        if ($request->has($field)) {
            $user->where($field, $request->input($field));
        }
    }

    //This field uses a LIKE match, handle it separately
    if ($request->has('email')) {
        $user->where('email', LIKE, '%' . $request->input('email') . '%');
    }

    //This field is a list of IDs
    if ($request->has('id')) {
        $ids = explode(',', $request->input('id'));
        $user->whereIn('id', $ids);
    }

    //Use pagination
    $users = $user->paginate(25);

    /**
     * Continue with the rest of response formatting below here
     */
}
```

You'll notice I used the paginate function to limit my results. When building an API endpoint that lists resources, you're going to want to put in your headers (my preference) or the response body information on how to get the first, previous, next, and last page of results. The Pagination feature in Laravel makes that easy, as it can construct most of the links using the `links()` method.

Unfortunately, you need to tell it what filter parameters were passed in the request so it can make sure it adds those to the links it generates. Otherwise you'll get links back without your filters, which doesn't do the client very much good for paging.

So here's a more complete example of recording filter parameters so they can be appended onto pagination links:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
    //Create a User object to append WHERE clauses onto
    $user = app('App\Models\User');

    //List of filters we found to append to links later
    $appends = [];

    //Run through our simple text fields
    foreach(['first_name', 'last_name', 'region', 'ip'] as $field) {
        if ($request->has($field)) {
            $appends[$field] = $request->input($field);
            $user->where($field, $request->input($field));
        }
    }

    //This field uses a LIKE match, handle it separately
    if ($request->has('email')) {
        $appends['email'] = $request->input('email');
        $user->where('email', LIKE, '%' . $request->input('email') . '%');
    }

    //This field is a list of IDs
    if ($request->has('id')) {
        $appends['id'] = $request->input('id');
        $ids = explode(',', $request->input('id'));
        $user->whereIn('id', $ids);
    }

    //Use pagination
    $users = $user->paginate(25);

    //Make sure we append our filter parameters onto the pagination object
    $users->appends($appends);

    //Now calling $users->links() will return the correct links with the right filter info

    /**
     * Continue with the rest of response formatting below here
     */
}
```

Pagination documentation can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination

For an example of how pagination linking can be awesomely done, check out Github's API documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

---

In the end it's not too far off from what you were doing, conceptually. The advantage here is that you move the code into the method that needs it, instead of having it run in your constructor every single time the controller is initialized, even if a different method will be called.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks mate! Really got me in the right track. Marking as answered.